# .htaccess remove multiple parameters from url

Tags: .htaccess

I need to remove all GET parameters from URL and get them by $_GET. The structure will be like this

From:

```
example.com/?section=DP&id=366
OR
example.com/index.php?section=DP&id=366
```

To:

```
example.com/something-dynamic-from-db,DP-366.html
```

How can i get this?

Comment: No, you cannot have a literal comma (",") in a URL, it is an invalid character in there. You _could_ go for `example.com/something-dynamic-from-db/DP-366.html` though...

Comment: @arkascha A literal comma is not "invalid" in the URL.

Comment: @DocRoot Correct, strictly speaking, the command is a "reserved character", so a character with a special meaning when used inside a URI (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). As such it is not "invalid" using it as demonstrated above. But the shown URL suggests a semantics that does _not_ fit the suggested usage, thus one can only advise against such construction. It poses a risk since you cannot rely on third party components to handle such a URL as you expect (undefined) and it reduces readability of the URL scheme.

Comment: @arkascha True, I certainly wouldn't recommend it. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have a literal comma (",") in a URL, it is an invalid character in there. You *could* go for `https://example.com/something-dynamic-from-db/DP-366.html` though. This should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
// some other. more specific rewriting rules here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RequestRule ^/?.+/(\w+)-(\d+)\.html$
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).